# How to plot visualization of missing values for big data in R?

Tags: r, plot, missing-data

I would like to draw a plot of missing values for a big data (1000 variables), I tried vis_miss function as follows

```
library(naniar)
vis_miss(predictors, warn_large_data=TRUE)
```

However, it shows the names of the variables after drawing the plot which is barely readable as there are too many variables, I was wondering 1. if there is any way to remove variable names from the x axis
2. Is there any other beautiful way to draw a missing value plot for big data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vis_miss()` function is ggplot-based, so you can change it relatively easily.

Regarding your question:

> 1. if there is any way to remove variable names from the x axis

You can remove them using e.g.

```
vis_miss(predictors, warn_large_data=TRUE) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

Or alter them using e.g.

```
vis_miss(predictors, warn_large_data=TRUE) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6, angle = 60))
```

And for your other question:

> 2. Is there any other beautiful way to draw a missing value plot for big data?

Without a sample of your actual data it is hard to say what would be best, but there are some suggestions such as `gg_miss_upset()` here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/naniar/vignettes/naniar-visualisation.html